# What is the use of Volley API in android?

Tags: java, android, android-volley, androidhttpclient

In my android apps development use instead of HTTPs go for volley API some one suggested me what is the difference between volley API and HTTPs thans!!

Comment: Volley can make connection in your Main thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Volley makes it much easier to handle responses as `String`s,
  `JSONObject`s and `JSONArray`s.
- Volley does the work on a separate thread internally, so no need for you to create an `AsyncTask`.
- Volley creates a central `RequestQueue` that performs HTTP requests serially.
- Volley allows you to easily synchronize pausing, resuming and cancelling of requests with the `Activity` / `Fragment` lifecycle.
- Volley with `okHttp` and `SPDY` is the fastest HTTP library out there.
- Volley also allows you to download images and display them in a `NetworkImageView`. Even if the image sizes are very large, Volley never seems to throw an `OutOfMemoryError`.